# What should I build my Angular 2 project with?

Tags: angular, build, angular-cli

I've built an Angular 2 web app, and it works great on my computer. But I went to build for production, and angular-cli built a "Hello World" App instead of using my files to build my project. I was using npm start to build it. Now I've kind of messed things up because I used ng serve, and now it's always using files in the src folder, instead of my app folder.

Anyways, my point is, once I fix this I would like to go down the proper path. What am I supposed to use to build my project? npm build? ng build? Should I be using Angular-Cli?

The Angular2 arena is changing so much I'm really not sure which path I'm supposed to be on anymore, is angular-cli the most up-to-date way of building Angular 2 projects? Should I be using ng build --prod?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion for building your application for production is to use the production environment `-prod` and ahead of time compilation `--aot` so your production build command will look like this:

```
ng build -prod --aot
```

Answer (score 2):

Production build will make a simplified version(light weight) of your  all the type script file. you can use any of the following command

```
# these are equivalent
ng build --target=production --environment=prod
ng build --prod --env=prod
ng build --prod
```